# Using Android Project Files in Separate Java Module?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project that uses ORMLite to access a database. For ORMLite I use POJO's to define the database schema.

I also have a Java project that I run to create a sqlite database that is used in the Android project. It'd be nice if the Java project could reference the same ORMLite POJOs in the Android project instead of having to copy them over. This would eliminate the possibility that the copy could get out of sync.

I'm using Gradle and Android Studio. I seem to be having some difficulty getting the android projects source files on the java projects class path. What am I doing wrong?

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task(createDB, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.example.java.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':AndroidProject')

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:${ORMLITE_VERSION}"   
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}
```

Comment: The Android plugin doesn't use the Java plugin's sourceSets; it has its own.

Comment: @ScottBarta so is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this really is to create another small project with only these POJOs and have it be a dependency of both the Android project and your other Java project.

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing that, but I guess it makes sense. Something unrelated, but I've wanted to ask you ever since merging manifests was put in the gradle build system. Do you guys ever have the intention of merging the <compatible-screens> tag with the manifests? Last I checked a month or so ago, it wasn't being merged.

Comment: Yes we have plan to vastly improve the manifest merger. Work on this should start soon actually.

Comment: Awesome. It will make my life much easier :-)